# About a divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ diverges, then prove that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia_i$ diverges.

My English is too bad to express the question clearly. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your english is actually total okay and I can understand your question. What have you tried so far and where did you got stuck?

Comment: I have tried proofs by contradiction and order test,but I failed.Then I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Can you provide a proof in detail?I had failed so much times.This question almost drived me crazy.

Comment: Are the terms positive, or not necessarily?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I've got it.